# Cannot return equation from function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to calculate the derivative and the integral using javascript, but when I try to return the use inputted equation. Nothing displays or a get a non-real answer.

`HTML`

```
Equation<br>
<input type="text" name="equation" id="equation" class="form"><br>
Point<br>
<input type="text" name="point" id="point" class="form"><br>
<p id="submit" onclick="submit()" name="solve">click</p><br>
```

JavaScript

```
function submit() {
    var equation = +document.getElementById("equation").value;
    var point = +document.getElementById("point").value;

    //console.log(point);
    var d = .0001;
    var a = (point +a)*a;

    var startPoint;

    function integral(f) {
        for(startPoint= 0; startPoint < point; startPoint+=d){
            intAnswer +=(f(startPoint+d)+f(startPoint-d))*(d)*(1/2);
        }
        return intAnswer;
    }
    function f(x) {
        return equation;
    }
    function diff(f) {
        return function(x) { 
            return ((f(x+a)-f(x-a))/(2*a));
        };
    }
}
```

I want to input `x*x` to get `X^2` but that does not work. Anyone know why?

Comment: You never call the function `f()`. You never call the function `diff()`. You never call `integral()` and `submit()` doesn't return any value. What do you think it should do?

Comment: apart from the fact that I'm not sure if in both diff and integral you are trying to reference the function f(), you are never ever calling these functions, neither self-executing them nor assigning them to a variable.

Comment: Also, having a function called `f` and function arguments also called `f` is confusing and may mislead you. Rename one of them to something else (maybe `g` or `ff`). If you think the argument has anything to do with the function `f` then you don't really understand your code.

Comment: Note that the `^` operator in JavaScript is the [XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR). To do powers, you must multiply by itself (like `x*x`) or use `Math.pow(x,2)`.

Comment: This is just part of the code that I needed help with, the rest of the code where I call is later on in the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to create function from input like this:

```
var f = new Function('x', 'return ' + equation);
```

This will evaluate your string.

Comment: @CupofJava, Watchout, no access to scoped variables. You need `eval` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your "equation" is just a string.
You can parse it by using eval.

```
f = function(x) {
    //x is your equation
    return eval(x);
}

//Note, user input formula must match the function parameter variable name( x ), if user types x*x then it works, if he types y*y then not.
```

Comment: The reason I did not go with this answer is because I am trying to avoid the `eval()` statement. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @CupofJava, Why? Using `new Function` is about as expensive as `eval`

Comment: @Pacerier I think he is concerned about certain security risks regarding eval()